# Fiber in Cable Management Arm

Tags: fibre-channel, cable-management

I'm aware of the existing debate on cable management arms.  For those people who DO use cable management arms, do you put Fiber into the arms?  It looks like I'm fine on minimum bend radii, but am looking for additional opinions before I do anything.

-Troy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have fibre in the management arms, havent experienced any problems yet.

(side-note: the management arms are soon going to be reconfigured as cargo for empty trash cans, they are *killing* my airflow)

Answer (score 1):

Where we need cable-arms we very frequently use OM2/3 MM fibres with them for FC traffic, so long as you're careful I don't see there being a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fibre cable is stronger than you might think.  You are almost certainly all right to do this.  As always, test first.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but isn't the entire concept of fiber optic cable built on the physics of light refraction?  If that's the case, I strongly suspect the minimum bend radius dicates not the breaking point of the fiber, but the point at which light may try to exit the fiber rather than refract off of the outside of the fiber.  Or might be totally wrong, cable engineering isn't my expertise =)

Comment: The rule-of-thumb is the radius of a tennis ball.

Comment: The OP already stated that the minimum bend radius wasn't an issue on his cable management arm.  I think he's just worried about rough handling of the cable.

Answer (score 1):

This is really pretty easy to figure out.

Find out from the reseller/manufacturer of your fibre cables what the maximum bend radius is. Then find out how far apart the cable runs are when the arm is fully folded shut. If the cable runs would be closer than the bend radius, then you can't run the fibre there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_radius

Answer (score 1):

We've been using fibre in management-arms for some time now with no impact to the performance of the fibre that we can tell.